# Linux C++ ptrace -- Map all cells of a child processes memorys

Tags: c++, linux, memory, ptrace

I have a linked list similar to this:

```
class MemoryCell
{
protected:
    unsigned char* _address; // the address offset (in another process)
    unsigned int _size;  // the size of this memory block
    unsigned char* _buffer; // the data

    MemoryCell* _next; // points to next memory cell to form linked list
};
```

Then I have a `MemoryMapper` class which will hold the head.  I want to get all of the memory cells in it.

```
// void MemoryMapper::MapAllCells(unsigned int procId)//
unsigned int offset = 0x0;
while (true)
    {
        long memoryData = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, procId, offset);
        if (memoryData == -1) break; // need to check for errno(3) too
       // add new MemoryCell w/ data to head of linked list
       // how to get next offset based on what was returned?
```

it breaks right away at address 0.  I thought it might start at 0x0 for that process but I guess I need the real offset.  But how can I get the next offset as well (based on size of previous)?

Hope it was clear but I can clarify if needed Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get this information from `ptrace()`; you can get it from `/proc/PID/maps` for the child process, though.  Note that address `0` is typically not mapped, in order to catch `NULL` pointer references, and may not make sense for `PTRACE_PEEKDATA` (separate I and D isn't generally used these days, and in its absence address 0 is usually text, not data; whether the kernel bothers to distinguish, I don't know off the top of my head).

Comment: interesting.  can you help point in the direction of making some sense of the data contained in the maps file?  std::<map> cluttering the search

Comment: I tried testing it on a process.  unsigned long long offset = 0x7f64e21c3000;  But it still breaks without reading?

Comment: What error do you get?  Is the process owned by your uid?  Do you otherwise have access to it (either via `PTRACE_ATTACH` or by it using being a child and invoking `PTRACE_TRACEME`)?

Comment: yea is owned by my uid... tried using PTRACE_ATTACH beforehand but still not working.  Not savvy enough from the man page how to tell which error I am getting.  http://pastebin.com/yF2rfSRw

Comment: hmm its failing on the attach too.. errno is 1.  then to read memory errno is 3

Comment: You should check `errno`, as with any other C system call, both with the `PTRACE_ATTACH` call and the `PTRACE_PEEKDATA` call.  I think I'd be using `/proc/PID/mem` instead of `ptrace()` if the memory (as opposed to registers, or stopping/tracing the program) is all you care about, by the way; also, reading memory is potentially quite meaningless while the program is running, I would suspect it wants you to stop the process so you get a meaningful snapshot of its memory.

Comment: Eventually I will need to overwrite the values, which I will probably need ptrace for?  btw when I try to read /proc/PID/mem from the terminal I need to do so as the superuser, and then it doesnt print anything out?  r00t@:/proc/27589$ more mem
mem: Permission denied
r00t@:/proc/27589$ sudo more mem
[sudo] password for r00t: 
r00t@:/proc/27589$

Comment: I think, if `more mem` makes sense to you, you don't quite have what you're trying to do worked out fully yet.  You should also look into what specific `errno` values mean.  I will however note that these failures are related.

Comment: memory editing is a traditional difficulty I have only played with in macroquest2.  I did `file mem` too and it said was empty.  I mean if its representing the actual memory I thought there'd be something in it but Im not some redhat certified engineer either.  Also have no idea which the error codes actually mean. Are these them?  1.  [EIO]  Specifies that the request parameter does not have one of the listed values, or is not valid for the machine type on which the process is  executing. ..... 3.   [EIO] Specifies that the addressed used is either out of bounds or improperly aligned. ?

Comment: ok, I read the manual (`man 3 errno` on Linux) for you:  `1` is `EPERM` ("Permission denied").  Neither `file` nor `du` will do anything sensible with `mem` because it isn't a real file, it a process's address space, and address 0 is not mapped (see start of this discussion); programs that expect files do not know what to do with this.

Comment: man this sucks why would it deny its owned by r00t and im running this program as r00t. when I ran it as root I could attach but not read.    side note: added you on twitter btw

Comment: Typically it's security-related.  I don't know specific details but you should not get that from `/proc/PID/mem` if your really are the same uid (try `ls -l`) and a quick test seems to work on the Linux systems I have accessible.

Comment: -rw------- 1 r00t r00t 0 2012-04-14 18:50 mem.... so yea owned by me...dunno why I need actual root to act on it.  I btw I'll look into ./mem in C++ more but only can you tell me if I can edit values in it?  If not ptrace driving me insane.

Comment: `write()` works (see `man 4 proc`); again, you probably need to stop the process before writing to its memory if you want anything like consistency.

Comment: man i dont even know im really bothered cuz I wrote the windows section of this code so easily and now I cant get it to work on linux.  gonna look into the write() of mem.. btw r00t@:/proc/6741$ man 4 proc
No manual entry for proc in section 4.... anyways thanks for the help deserve the selected answer i gave cuz no1 else knows wtf